# sql select all for one table only

Tags: php, sql, postgresql

I have a couple joins that I'm doing. I say tablename.column to identify what I want to select in the database...don't want to select all columns. However, my last join I do want to select all for that. Is there a way I can use an asterisk or something for the last join?

The last table is going to be dynamic too so I can't hard code it in (although I could write it out dynamically) but thought there might be an easier way.

```
    SELECT content_name.name,
           house.listing,
           street.* 
      FROM content 
INNER JOIN house ON content_name.id=house.id 
 LEFT JOIN street ON content_name.id=street.id;
```

Comment: What you have should work in `MySQL` and from what I can tell `postgresql` as well. Can you elaborate on the dynamic part?

Comment: The question is a sql question...I added postgresql and mysql tags because either community could answer it. 

Based on certain information (who is logged in, what organization they are with, what file they are working with)...when they edit information that info will go to their own table. Each organization has their own table so they can have their own unique data for that particular item. So based on certain criteria my php will write a query together based on who it is. All this works well.

Just wondering if there was an easy way to say select * from just one table and not the rest.

Answer (score 39):

Alias your last table the same way everytime, and then just .* your alias.

```
SELECT content_name.name,house.listing, last_table.* 
FROM content INNER JOIN house ON 
content_name.id=house.id 
LEFT JOIN street last_table ON content_name.id=last_table.id;
```

That being said, *** in a production query is an accident waiting to happen.**

Comment: +1: It's the part about the "last table is going to be dynamic" that freaks me out...

Comment: dynamic in the sense I control it in my php...nothing comes from the user.

Comment: Keith: If you're seperating out users/customers into different tables, I would consider a common table name in different schemas and then just set your "search_path" depending on where they need to look.  It should make alot of those kind of dynamic queries simpler.